# Using Packages on mac but the post-installation script not work well when installing

Tags: macos, shell, package

I'm using [packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html) to pack my node js project into a installer to work on mac. Things I do are
1. copy files to user's computer(one directory to put node project, and one directory to put a library)
2. run a .sh file to start my node server

part 1 went well, all files copy to the desired places. But after I put post-installation script into the scripts section, the build is OK but when running it stops at the run script stage and the installation cannot be halted...

The script is as follows:

## !/bin/bash

/Users/Shared/xxx/node /Users/Shared/xxx/hipkiLocalServer.js
exit 0

and it can be executed standalone by double clicking it...

I have no idea what to do.. anyone has any suggestion? Or are there ways other than "packages" that can do the things I want to do?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try Iceberg:  http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Iceberg.html

Also, you're missing a semicolon (or carriage return) in that script:

```
/Users/Shared/xxx/node /Users/Shared/xxx/hipkiLocalServer.js; exit 0
```